# Uploading another version of an iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, submit

I want to upload another version of my current app, but the problem is that i lost the original Xcode project of the app. Can i start another project and set the bundle identifier to be the same and upload the project? or that won't be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be possible. It should work without any problems. But don't forget to use the same account.

You app is bound to the identifier, as the word identifier says.